# Do I get only one preorder bonus or one per character?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I am wondering if the Preorder bonus (the stone thats makes you change you lightsaber color) is only once, or one for every character you create?

Also, do you get one later in the game if you didn't preorder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every character you create, on any server, will get all the pre-order and/or Digital Deluxe/Collector's Edition items. They come in an in-game mail as soon as you create the new character.

So don't worry about using them; each character gets their own copies. :)

You can purchase with in-game credits several of these items without buying those packages, if you get a security key (hardware or software versions). But not all of them. Some are exclusive.

Also, Bioware does allow you to later buy the Digital Deluxe/Collector's Edition later, and add those keys on to your existing account which will give you access (plus the 1 free month of play) on top of whatever you already have.

Comment: You can purchase the pre-order crystal from a vendor for 10c. I think the vendor is in the VIP lounge at fleet so you need a VIP bracelet (part of the pre-order package) to access the vendor.

Comment: @BlueSixty you don't need a VIP bracelet to access the pre-order crystal vendor. They're on the main level of the fleet station's outer ring, hidden in a corner near an exit of the "craft" quadrant.