# Can the green/black color crystal from Razer be used with all my characters?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Buying [a Razer peripheral for The Old Republic](http://www.razerzone.com/swtor) gives you access to a green/black color crystal.  As with the yellow/black preorder crystal, do I get one for every character I create?  Is it bind on pickup?  Is it limited to light-aligned characters or does it have any other limitations?

Comment: Out of curiosity, since I don't have access to the Preorder crystals: Does the vendor sell scaling crystals up to max level as well? Or are they only useful for low level characters?

Comment: Not an answer to all these questions, but a few: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/42293/1134

Comment: @Mufasa that doesn't answer his question at all. He's asking whether the Razer promo items work the same way as the CE/Preorder stuff, not how the CE/Preorder stuff works.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Only a +4 endurance color crystal is sold, for 10 credits each. Each new character is mailed one for free when the character is created. So yes, they are only for low level characters. Note: *At this moment*

Comment: The preorder crystals do not scale. Every character I create get's my yellow/black one (its +4end) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you redeem the code to your account the green/black color crystal from Razer is mailed to all your characters. I also heard that it is mailed to every new character you make though I have not tryed it yet. You will be given 2 crystals for each character BoP, I don't know if you can buy them from a vender like the preorder ones so try not to lose them. The crystals do not have limitations so light, dark, and inbetween can use them.

Comment: I would guess it is, as the Preorder Yellow/Black crystals

Comment: Having finally created an alt I can confirm that you immediately get mailed the green/black crystals.