# Can you upgrade normal to collector's edition

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I have been playing SWTOR since launch but I have now just seen a local game store selling collector's edition boxes for cheap (comparatively). I'm tempted to buy one but I wouldn't really want a second account, I'd just want to upgrade my current account to a collector's edition one.

Does anybody know if it is possible to use the collector's edition key in some way to upgrade a normal pre-order account (the only bonus I have is the colour crystal, nothing else).

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/42293/1134

Comment: You can also just pay $20 to upgrade your account to Collector's Edition, which is probably cheaper than buying a separate Collector's Edition. You can do that [here](https://account.swtor.com/user/digitalupgrade)

Comment: @SaintWacko: I am considering it for the items in the CE box as much as anything but it is definitely a useful note for others considering a similar thing. :)

Comment: Oh, *Collector's Edition*! My bad, I was getting that confused with the Digital Deluxe Edition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Subject: Upgrading to Collectors Edition
>
> As it has correctly been stated you will be able to upgrade your
>   edition of the game.
>
> If you wish to do this, when you have your product code, go to the
>   code redemption area of your account and input the code. This will
>   then upgrade your account to the relative edition.

Sources: http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=42785 and http://www.swtor.com/support/helpcenter/4064

Comment: You shouldn't apologize for answering your own question. [It's even encouraged.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: can I ask, if you do this, then is the CE code seperate from the product registration key? So could I buy the CE, apply the collectable bit to my account and then give the game to a friend to make a new account with?

Comment: @TZHX: I think that there is a single code for the CE. You can however apply it to an existing account which will upgrade it to CE and give you 30 more days of game time (so the same benefits as if it were a new account). I may pick up the collector's edition later though so if I find out differently I will come back and update.

Comment: Attention: You will not get 30 more days when you tie the code to an existing account. The 30 days gametime apply only once per account.